# Python script and class in the same file

Tags: python, linux, permissions

I have a Python class that supposes to perform some tasks in the background by submitting itself to a cluster environment. e.g.

```
class AwesomeTaskController(object):
    def run(bunch_of_tasks):
        for task in bunch_of_tasks:
            cmd = "%s %s" % (os.path.abspath(__file__), build_cli_paramters(task))
            # call the API to submit the cmd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #blah blah do stuff with given parameters
```

All is well for the first time that this class was run. When it was run the first time, a pyc file is created. This pyc file isn't executable (permission wise).

So the 2nd time I use this class, the command will use the pyc directly and complains that permission is denied. Perhaps I am approaching this from the wrong angle?

Comment: I only know that I need to write PBS scripts for them.

Answer (score 0):

.pyc files aren't executable themselves; you always have to execute the .py file. The .pyc file is just a compiled version of the .py file that Python generates on the fly to save itself some time the next time you run the .py file.

In your case, all you should need to do is check to see if `__file__` ends with ".pyc" and remove the trailing "c". You could do that by, say, replacing `__file__` in your script with:

```
(__file__[:-1] if __file__.endswith(".pyc") else __file__)
```

and that should solve your problem.